# How is the central atom in SNF3, Nitrogen?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, lewis-structure

Shouldn't it be Sulphur as it is larger and has ability to make more bonds due to its 6 valence electrons?

Comment: It *is* sulfur https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiazyl_trifluoride

Comment: The formula is not written in structural order. It's written in electronegativity order.

Answer (score 3):

Thiazyl trifluoride $(\ce{NSF3})$ is a chemical compound of nitrogen, sulfur, and fluorine, first reported in 1956. Its structure has been suggested to have the framework $\ce{F2S=NF}$ based on hydrolysis experiments. However, it was revised in 1961, based on infrared and fluorine nuclear magnetic resonance data by Richert and Glemser who have correctly interpreted the structure in favor of $\ce{N#SF3}$ (Ref. 1), which was confirmed unambiguously and quantitatively by mass and microwave spectroscopies (Ref. 2). According to Ref.2, the SN-bond length $(\pu{1.416 Å})$ is short, which is in the range expected for a triple bond of $\ce{N#S}$ from theoretical calculations:

[image]

The above structure is confirmed later again by crystallographic data (Ref.3). Accordingly, bond distances and angles in $\ce{N#SF3}$ in the solid state (X-ray diffraction, Ref.3) and gas phase (microwave spectroscopy, Ref.2) are well correlated.

---

**References:**

1. Hans Richert and Oskar Glemser, "Schwefel-Stickstoff-Fluorverbindungen. XI. Struktur einiger Schwefel—Stickstoff—Fluorverbindungen," *Zeitschrift für anorganische und allgemeine Chemie* **1961**, *307(5-6)*, 328-344 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1002/zaac.19613070512).
2. William H. Kirchhoff and E. Bright Wilson, Jr., "The Microwave Spectrum and Structure of $\ce{NSF3}$," *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1962**, *84(3)*, 334–336 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00862a003).
3. Tobias Borrmann, Enno Lork, Rüdiger Mews, Simon Parsons, Jan Petersen, Wolf-Dieter Stohrer, and Paul G. Watson, "The crystal structures of $\ce{NSF3}$ and $\ce{(NSF2N(CH3)CH2–)2}$: How short is the ‘Crystallographic’ $\ce{N#S}$ triple bond?," *Inorganica Chimica Acta* **2008**, *361(2)*, 479-486 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ica.2007.05.016).